# cmake can't find BLAS installed via package manager

Tags: cmake, blas

I have a Makefile-based project that needs to link against the BLAS linear algebra library.  There are a huge number of different versions of this library, so trying to find it using make rules would be painful, to say the least.  Luckily cmake has a FindBLAS.cmake module that *should* make it easier. Except that I can't get it to work.

On CentOS7 with both `blas-devel` and `openblas-devel` installed via yum, I can do

```
> ldconfig -p | grep blas
    libopenblas64_.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblas64_.so.0
    libopenblas64_.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblas64_.so
    libopenblas64.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblas64.so.0
    libopenblas64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblas64.so
    libopenblasp64_.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblasp64_.so.0
    libopenblasp64_.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblasp64_.so
    libopenblasp64.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblasp64.so.0
    libopenblasp64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblasp64.so
    libopenblasp.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblasp.so.0
    libopenblasp.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblasp.so
    libopenblaso64_.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblaso64_.so.0
    libopenblaso64_.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblaso64_.so
    libopenblaso64.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblaso64.so.0
    libopenblaso64.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblaso64.so
    libopenblaso.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblaso.so.0
    libopenblaso.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblaso.so
    libopenblas.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblas.so.0
    libopenblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libopenblas.so
    libgslcblas.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libgslcblas.so.0
    libblas.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libblas.so.3
    libblas.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libblas.so
```

so both `libblas.so` and `libopenblas.so` are in default library paths.  And, if I simply give `-lblas` or `-lopenblas` to my linker, everything works fine. But, when I try to use cmake to find it automatically, I get

```
> cmake3 --find-package -DCOMPILER_ID=GNU -DLANGUAGE=CXX -DMODE=EXIST -DNAME=BLAS
BLAS not found.
CMake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.
```

cmake is version 3.12, and the same command works for other packages (Java, Boost, Git, etc). FindBLAS.cmake is where I would expect it at `/usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindBLAS.cmake`.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Just a note from the CMake [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-the-find-package-tool), using `find-package` like this is *not* well-supported. Did you try editing your CMake file to use the `find_package(BLAS ...)` command?

Comment: @squareskittles I missed that note in the docs.  This project currently uses a regular Makefile...a full conversion to cmake is more than I had planned to do right now